# Count records in one table where there are no records in linked table matching certain criteria

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

T1:

```
  id   | name
------ | ------
   1   | Bob  
   2   | John  
   3   | Joe
```

T2:

```
  id   | T1_id  |  type
------ | ------ | ------ 
   1   |   1    |  call
   2   |   1    |  email
   3   |   1    |  fax
   4   |   2    |  call
   5   |   2    |  email
   6   |   2    |  fax
   7   |   3    |  call
   8   |   3    |  email
```

I want to count the number of records in T1 which **do not** have a record in T2 with a type of 'fax'.

So the answer in this case would be **1** (3|Joe)

Currently I have:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `T1`
JOIN `T2` on `T1`.`id` = `T2`.`T1_id`
WHERE `T2`.`type` != 'fax'
```

But this is obviously counting all the records which are not 'fax'. I just cant get the logic in my head.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subquery is unnecessary:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) 
  FROM t1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN t2 
    ON t2.t1_id = t1.id 
   AND t2.type = 'fax' 
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: For those interested, this technique (left joining, then checking for null values) is called a left anti-semi join

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me (as did the others, but this was the most useful for what I wanted)

Comment: @e_i_pi thanks, I've not come across that before. Having no formal training in the subject, I always refer to this as an exclusion join.

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*)
from
(
    SELECT t1.id
    FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T2 on T1.id = T2.T1_id
    GROUP BY t1.id
    HAVING sum(T2.type = 'fax') = 0
) tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers given by Strawberry and juergen d are correct, but for completeness, here's another example using `NOT EXISTS`. All the queries will have different execution plans, so depending on your data in `T1` and `T2` YMMV:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `T1`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `T2`
    WHERE `T2`.`T1_id` = `T1`.`id`
    AND `T2`.`type` = 'fax'
)
```